# Using XSLT to turn content of WYSIWYG stored in XML into HTML

Tags: html, xml, xslt

The CMS I use uses the Xalan XSLT processor which is a XSLT version 1.0 processor. Editors who use WYSIWYG fields within the CMS can save content that will look like either:

```
<story>
    <p>Story Text which may have <em>formatting</em>.</p>
</story>
```

or:

```
<story>Story Text which may have <em>formatting</em>.</story>
```

or even:

```
<story>
    <div>Story Text which may<br /> have <em>formatting</em>.</div>
</story>
```

In order to handle those varying cases I've been using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/> 
<xsl:template match="/system-index-block">
    <xsl:for-each select="story">
        <xsl:choose>
            <!-- If wrapped in an element -->
            <xsl:when test="./p|./div">
                <!-- copy what is inside story, allow for text outside of elements -->
                <xsl:copy-of select="./text()|./*"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- wrap the content in a paragraph tag -->
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <p>
                    <!-- copy text and tags from inside story -->
                    <xsl:copy-of select="./text()|./*"/>
                </p>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Is there a better way of producing well formed HTML from this data? Is there a way to simply this?

Comment: I don't know how complex the "real" XML will be, but if you only have XHTML wrapped in `<story>` elements you could simply replace those with `<div>`s. If it's more complicated it would be useful to see an example (for example, could there be `<story>`s within `<story>`s?)

Comment: The real XML is more complex. There are never nested `<story>` elements. The `<story>` element contains the post processed output of a TinyMCE instance and in most cases the editors are restricted from using the "Edit HTML Source" button within that editor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should change your mindset when working with XSLT: look at it as a functional language, where you declare rules for the transformation of elements. Think about it in terms of events: when a p element is found in input, I expect this and that in the output.

First, regarding the definition of your data. You should ask for (or create) a more formal description of the data. There are different formats available to describe the structure (grammar), [DTD](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Document_Type_Definition) and [XML Schema](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/) being the more common. There are more simple alternatives such as [RELAX NG](http://relaxng.org/) and [Schematron](http://www.schematron.com/).

My guess, from your stylesheet and your descriptions:

- there is always a `<system-index-block>` at the top
- there is a list of `<story>` elements in `<system-index-block>`
- there is mixed HTML contents in `<story>`, with `<p>`,`<div>`,`<br>`,`<em>` and text allowed

I am not sure about the last part: is it possible to have both text and div or paragraph at the top level in a story?

```
<story>
  Text before a <p>Paragraph</p> in between or <div>Div</div> even after ?
</story>
```

You should break your unique template rule into several template rules, one or several for each element. Then to direct the flow from rule to rule, do not use for-each but rather apply-templates:

```
<xsl:template match="system-index-block">
  <!-- Note:
       You probably need to create the basic HTML structure Here: html, head, body
  -->
  <xsl:apply-templates /> <!-- you can specify select="story" but it is not required -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="story[p|div]"> <!-- If wrapped in an element -->
   <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="story"> <!-- wrap the content in a paragraph tag -->
  <p>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy" />
  </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that I used the mode "copy" above: you can now create different rules for the same nodes depending on the mode, for example:

```
<xsl:template match="text()" /> <!-- ignore text in normal mode, probably whitespace -->

<xsl:template match="text()" mode="copy">
    <xsl:copy />
</xsl:template>
```

Also, you will probably get into trouble because you only declared a namespace for the xsl prefix. You typically need a prefix/namespace declaration for the input and output formats. You will then need to use the prefix in match/select expressions and in the tag names for the output, for example, with input prefix bound to your input namespace and html bound to the html namespace:

```
<xsl:template match="input:story"> <!-- wrap the content in a paragraph tag -->
  <html:p>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy" />
  </html:p>
</xsl:template>
```

To go further, here are pointers that you will probably find useful:

- [Namespaces and XSLT Stylesheets](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/04/04/trxml/index.html)
- [Identity transformation](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Identity_transform)

Comment: Good answer considering the degree to which I tried to simplify the example XML and XSL. I tried to boil the question down and see now that I left out useful information. I'll look at reworking things to include greater use of `mode=""`. I'm going to review my use of `<xsl:for-each` throughout all of my code and see where I'm relying on it where it isn't needed. The namespace isn't an issue as the stylesheet is only generating a portion of a page.

Comment: The only case this seems to break on the way it is layed out now is when `<story>` contains both unenclosed text and `<p>` tags.

Comment: @Jason can you edit your answer to show your updated code?